# Declare a local variable as number/integer in ibatis

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008, ibatis

```
DECLARE

CommitCmpt int; HERE the variable to use it later

 BEGIN

INSERT INTO test....

Commitcmpt := CommitCmpt + 1 ;

END;
```

I am getting an error on this line:

```
 CommitCmpt int;

com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:  
--- Cause: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: 'int' is not a recognized CURSOR option.
```

Any help?

I am using Ibatis to insert records into an sql server 2008 table

Answer (score 0):

[Local variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258839%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) names should begin with an `@` symbol, otherwise it will think it's a [cursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx).

Comment: Ok thanks Dave i will try it. Do you have other solution to limit the ibatis to commit on a specific number of records?